# Multiple date ranges using CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I need to generate a table of half hour periods. I have the following which works:

```
WITH ctePeriods AS
(
  SELECT  @gapStart HalfHourPeriod
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, HalfHourPeriod)
  FROM    ctePeriods  
  WHERE   HalfHourPeriod <  DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, @gapEnd)
)
```

Which gives me the values for the range between @gapStart and @gapEnd.

However I also have a table of ranges which I need to generate:

```
create table #gaps(HHFrom datetime, HHTo datetime)
```

Currently I'm using this to get the values for @gapStart and @gapEnd used above by getting the min and max from #gaps. But this means I'm filling in more rows then I need in ctePeriods.

Is there any way that I can use the rows in #gaps within ctePeriods so I only create the rows that I need?

Comment: Can you maybe supply us with your expected results?

Comment: Also include some data... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer using a Tally Table for things like this. You can use a persisted Tally Table, or you create one on the fly (as I do here):

```
CREATE TABLE #gaps (HHFrom datetime,
                    HHTo datetime);

INSERT INTO #gaps (HHFrom,
                   HHTo)
VALUES('20190101','20190103'),
      ('20190217','20190315'),
      ('20190708',GETDATE());
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6), --1000000 rows, feel free to increase/decrease per your own requirement
Dates AS(
    SELECT G.HHFrom,
           G.HHTo,
           DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*T.I, G.HHFrom) AS HH
    FROM #gaps G
         CROSS JOIN Tally T
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*T.I, G.HHFrom) <= G.HHTo)
SELECT *
FROM Dates D
ORDER BY D.HHFrom, D.HH;

GO

DROP TABLE #gaps;
```

Unlike an rCTE, this means that for large ranges the statement won't "fall over" if you have more than 100 rows (the default recursion), and  isn't recursive like an rCTE.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want. Many thanks. Having used a CTE in the past for this I was hooked into using it again and hadn't thought there may be another way.